# Equivalent of print_r function in Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony

I just wanted to know if there is this function in Symfony2 that would print human-readable information about a variable (the same as print_r() in PHP)?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `{{ dump(the_variable) }}` function from Twig.
It is a helper, equivalent of var_dump in PHP, contained in a output buffer.

To enable such function, please check that in your `config.yml` file, this is configured:

```
twig:
    ...
    debug:%kernel.debug%
```

Comment: Just a notice, the `dump` function is only available when running `Twig` in `debug` mode

Comment: @DarkBee You're right, I was guessing too much. Edited the answer.